# On completion of tests open HtmlTestRunner report

Tags: python, python-unittest

I've been given the task of opening the report generated by `HtmlTestRunner` on completion of the tests. When the line `unittest.main()` (abbreviated) is commented out the remaining code opens the most recent report generated but the tests do not run. When the line `unittest.main()` is not commented out the tests run but no report is opened. I can confirm with my debugger that the issue is not with the code that opens reports as when `unittest.main()` is present any breakpoints after it aren't hit.

```
def main():
    unittest.main(testRunner=HtmlTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(output="./"))
    # Code for opening reports goes here

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to bypass the default call to `sys.exit()`

```
unittest.main(testRunner=HtmlTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(output="./"), exit=False)
```

I've never done so myself, however.